# Haskell - Transform a list of unions into a tuple of lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm looking for a way to transform a list into an n-tuple with one list for each of the n constructors in a disjoint union. The standard library defines a similar function specifically for `Either`s:

```hs
partitionEithers :: [Either a b] -> ([a], [b])
```

I'm looking for techniques for solving the generalized problem with the following requirements:

- convenient to write
- as little boilerplate as possible
- processes the list in a single pass
- datatype-generics, metaprogramming, existing libraries etc are all permitted

###### Example

Here is an example specification with two proposed solutions:

```hs
partitionSum :: [MySum] -> ([A], [B], [C], [D])

data MySum
  = CaseA A
  | CaseB B
  | CaseC C
  | CaseD D

data A = A deriving Show
data B = B deriving Show
data C = C deriving Show
data D = D deriving Show

-- expect "([A,A],[B,B,B],[],[D])"
test :: IO ()
test = print . partitionSum $
  [CaseD D, CaseB B, CaseA A, CaseA A, CaseB B, CaseB B]
```

First attempt: *n* list comprehensions that traverse the list *n* times.

```
partitionSum1 :: [MySum] -> ([A], [B], [C], [D])
partitionSum1 xs =
  ( [a | CaseA a <- xs]
  , [b | CaseB b <- xs]
  , [c | CaseC c <- xs]
  , [d | CaseD d <- xs]
  )
```

Second attempt: a single traversal of the input list. I have to manually thread the state through the fold which makes the solution a little repetitive and annoying to write.

```
partitionSum2 :: [MySum] -> ([A], [B], [C], [D])
partitionSum2 = foldr f ([], [], [], [])
  where
    f x (as, bs, cs, ds) =
      case x of
        CaseA a -> (a : as, bs, cs, ds)
        CaseB b -> (as, b : bs, cs, ds)
        CaseC c -> (as, bs, c : cs, ds)
        CaseD d -> (as, bs, cs, d : ds)
```

Comment: An idea might be to work with *template Haskell* that will construct the function itself, although template Haskell is a controversial topic.

Comment: Here is a generalization I once wrote [`partition :: Representable r => Foldable f => Eq (Rep r) => (a -> Rep r) -> f a -> r [a]`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6q8sev/reversing_representable_functors_radix_sort_trie/dkwmcjl/) based on [representable functors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [`Representable` answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6q8sev/reversing_representable_functors_radix_sort_trie/dkwmcjl/):

---

A thing that came to me from seeing `foldr f ([], [], [], [])` was to define a monoid where the nil case is `mempty`

```
{-# DerivingVia #-}
..
import GHC.Generics (Generically(..), ..)

type Classify :: Type
type Classify = C [A] [B] [C] [D]
  deriving
  stock Generic

  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via Generically Classify

-- mempty = C [] [] [] []
-- C as bs cs ds <> C as1 bs1 cd1 ds1 = C (as ++ as1) (bs ++ bs1) (cs ++ cs1) (ds ++ ds1)
```

[`Generically`](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/5726) will be exported from `GHC.Generics` in the future. It defines `Classify` as a semigroup and monoid through generic pointwise lifting.

With this all you need is a classifier function, that classifies a `MySum` into `Classify` and you can define `partition` in terms of `foldMap`

```
classify :: MySum -> Classify
classify = \case
  SumA a -> C [a] [] [] []
  SumB b -> C [] [b] [] []
  SumC c -> C [] [] [c] []
  SumD d -> C [] [] [] [d]

partition :: Foldable f => f MySum -> Classify
partition = foldMap classify
```

Answer (score 1):

As your function is a transformation from sums to products, there's a fairly simple implementation using [`generics-sop`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop). This is a library which enhances GHCs generics with more specialized types that make induction on algebriac type (i.e. sums of products) simpler.

First, a prelude:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Generics.SOP hiding ((:.:))
import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
import GHC.Generics ((:.:)(..))


partitionSum :: (Generic t) => [t] -> NP ([] :.: NP I) (Code t)
```

This is the method you want to write. Let's examine its type.

- the single argument is a list of some generic type. Pretty straightforward. Note here that `Generic` is the one from `generics-sop`, not from GHC
- the returned value is an n-ary product (n-tuple) where each element is a list composed with `NP I` (itself an n-ary product, because generally, algebraic datatype constructors might have more than one field)
- `Code t` is the sum-of-products type representation of `t`. It's a list of lists of type. e.g. `Code (Either a b) ~ '[ '[a], '[b] ]`. The generic value representation of `t` is `SOP I (Code t)` - a sum of of products over the "code".

To implement this, we can convert each `t` to its generic representation, then fold over the resulting list:

```
partitionSum = partitionSumGeneric . map from

partitionSumGeneric :: SListI xss => [SOP I xss] -> NP ([] :.: NP I) xss
partitionSumGeneric = foldr (\(SOP x) -> classifyGeneric x) emptyClassifier
```

`partitionSumGeneric` is pretty much the same as `partitionSum`, but operates on generic representations of values.

Now for the interesting part. Let's begin with the base case of our fold. This should contain empty lists in every position. `generics-sop` provides a handy mechanism for generating a product type with a uniform value in each position:

```
emptyClassifier :: SListI xs => NP ([] :.: NP I) xs
emptyClassifier = hpure (Comp1 [])
```

The recursive case is as follows: if the value has tag at index `k`, add that value to the list at index `k` in the accumulator. We can do this with simultaneous recursion on both the sum type (it's generic now, so a value of type `NS (NP I) xs` - a sum of products) and on the accumulator.

```
classifyGeneric :: NS (NP I) xss -> NP ([] :.: NP I) xss -> NP ([] :.: NP I) xss
classifyGeneric (Z x)  (Comp1 l :* ls) = (Comp1 $ x : l) :* ls
classifyGeneric (S xs) (      l :* ls) =              l  :* classifyGeneric xs ls
```

Your example with some added data to make it a bit more interesting:

```
data MySum
  = CaseA A
  | CaseB B
  | CaseC C
  | CaseD D

-- All that's needed for `partitionSum' to work with your type
deriving instance GHC.Generic MySum
instance Generic MySum

data A = A Int deriving Show
data B = B String Int deriving Show
data C = C deriving Show
data D = D Integer deriving Show

test = partitionSum $
  [CaseD $ D 0, CaseB $ B "x" 1, CaseA $ A 2, CaseA $ A 3, CaseB $ B "y" 4, CaseB $ B "z" 5]
```

the result is:

```
Comp1 {unComp1 = [I (A 2) :* Nil,I (A 3) :* Nil]} :* Comp1 {unComp1 = [I (B "x" 1) :* Nil,I (B "y" 4) :* Nil,I (B "z" 5) :* Nil]} :* Comp1 {unComp1 = []} :* Comp1 {unComp1 = [I (D 0) :* Nil]} :*Nil
```